# A method to determine total number of objects in memory for PHP?

Tags: php

I want to know the number of objects that are currently in memory. Ideally I'd be able to call something like memory_get_peak_usage to get the peak number of objects in memory as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to ask: What is the main reason for this? Is this for research? Or is this just for debugging?

I'm pretty sure there isn't a "core way" to do this.

In any event you can try using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/) to see if you can get some of the information you need.

Comment: On a page with a lot of objects I'm hitting an out of memory exception on my production server. I'm trying to track it down and determining the total number of objects seemed like a good place to start.

Comment: Well, we aware xdebug will kill the performance of that server. I recommend you if you have more that one webserver just install it just in one of them, then check and disable and enabled it on demand.

Comment: I'm not using xdebug on the production server.